# How to configure python-lsp-server in NvChad

Tags: python, neovim, nvim-lspconfig

I have been using the NvChad configuration for neovim for a while after switching from VSCode. As I am new to configuring vim I took help from an youtube video.
[This is the video my setup is based upon: ]
(https://youtu.be/4BnVeOUeZxc?si=Xatala9e71x0eRtC).

But as of now null-ls is archived and some functionalities does not work properly. I have pylsp installed through mason, but I don't know how to configure it and I need some help with that.

I have tried to setup the lsp server in my nvim/lua/custom/config/lspconfig.lua file but it does not seem to work properly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you're new to configuring Neovim, I don't think its a good idea to start with pre-made "distributions". Instead, slowly start adding pieces of functionality you need and take the time to understand how each component works and configure it to your preference. A better starting point is [TJ DeVries' kickstart.nvim](https://youtu.be/stqUbv-5u2s?si=Gs4C2tlpWVyYwlNL) video and the associated [config file](https://github.com/nvim-lua/kickstart.nvim). Watch the video, start with a clean config, comment out all functionality and add in pieces one piece at a time.

Answer (score 0):

navigate to .config/nvim/lua/custom/configs/lspconfig.lua

and find the line that says local servers = {...} in that array just add the string "pylsp"

Answer (score 0):

#### Here is the common pattern on configuring lspconfig on NvChad.

[Here][1] is the link of documentation on NvChad about setting up the lspconfig.

If we take a look step by step, first you need to have this code

```
    -- In order to modify the `lspconfig` configuration:
{
  "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
   config = function()
      require "plugins.configs.lspconfig"
      require "custom.configs.lspconfig"
   end,
},
```

inside of your

```
> ~/.config/nvim/lua/custom/plugins.lua
```

file.

**Second**, you have to install the lsp server via mason. Here is how would an example
custom/plugins.lua would look like with the previous two steps:

```
local plugins = {
  {
  "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
   config = function()
      require "plugins.configs.lspconfig"
      require "custom.configs.lspconfig"
   end,
  },
  {
    "williamboman/mason.nvim",
    opts = {
      ensure_installed = {
        "lua-language-server",
        "html-lsp",
        "prettier",
        "stylua",
        "gopls"
      },
    },
  }
}

return plugins
```

After you included the mason code as well, you could call MasonInstallAll while in the command mode, `:MasonInstallAll`

**Third**, we have to configure the lspconfig. Consider `custom/plugins.lua` as where we declare the plugins we desire to configure. It is recommended to create a file for each plugin configuration.

You could do your

```
~/.config/nvim/lua/custom/configs/luaconfig.lua
```

Here is how the configuration would look like according to the document.

```
local on_attach = require("plugins.configs.lspconfig").on_attach
local capabilities = require("plugins.configs.lspconfig").capabilities

local lspconfig = require "lspconfig"
local servers = { "gopls"--[[ , "html", "css"  ]]}

for _, lsp in ipairs(servers) do
  lspconfig[lsp].setup {
    on_attach = on_attach,
    capabilities = capabilities,
  }
end
```

In this file, you could also configure them according to your liking. Every lsp server have some configurations they would recommend etc. For example here is how gopls lspconfig setup looks like:

```
lspconfig.gopls.setup({
  on_attach = on_attach,
  capabilities = capabilities,
  settings = {
    gopls = {
      analyses = {
        unusedparams = true,
      },
      staticcheck = true,
      gofumpt = true,
    },
  },
})
```